# Are variables in mathematic algorithm syntax scoped like in programming languages?

Tags: algorithms

In a programming language, a variable is only valid in its own scope and can be redeclared in another scope, such as:

```
{
int i = 4;
}
{
double i = 1.2;
}
```

But how is it in algorithms described using a sequence of mathematical formulas and variables occurring inside functions and limits, lower bounds and so on?

For example, can I write $i = \arg max_{i=1}^{n} f(i)$ or is it an error to use the variable $i$ twice?

Edit: To clarify, I mean if I can assign the expression to the variable $i$ or if I need to assign it to a different variable, e.g. $j$.

Comment: There would be little purpose in even using it once if the two occurrences had nothing to do with each other. The occurrence as a subscript to $\operatorname{argmax}$ *binds* $i$, the occurrence in $f(i)$ *is bound*, they refer to the same object. How could it possibly be an error to use it twice? That would make it impossible to say things like $\Sigma_{i=0}^n i = n(n+1)/2$, or $\lim_n x_n \to 0$, etc.

Comment: But your programming language example is not a good analogue of the argmax example. They show two different scopes for the same variable. The argmax example is just one scope. It's more like, say, one comprehension in Python: `max(f(i) for i in range(n+1))`. Bound variables in mathematics don't have a value outside their scope, they don't "leak".

Comment: Ah, I totally missed the fact that you're assigning $i = \operatorname{argmax}_i $... . But, not a problem, given what I said about bound variables "not leaking": it's ok to use $i$ on the lefthand side. But probably it would be more typical (and easier to understand) to use a variant of the variable, such as $i_{max} =\operatorname{argmax}_{i=0}^n f(i)$.

Comment: As BrianO said, this is not technically wrong but it's not typical. I would describe it as poor mathematical style.